# Can I redirect from a URL to another without running ZF2 application twice?

Tags: php, http, redirect, zend-framework2, http-redirect

I want to redirect a user from one url to another. I used `$this->redirect()->toRoute()` but i've noticed that the application runs twice as if the user made 2 requests.

Comment: Can you use `header` function?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have 2 requests. Because the following will happen:

1. Request to /someroute
2. Response from someroute will contain "go to /otherroute"
3. Request to /otherroute
4. Response HTML

Maybe a workaround is not to use `redirect()`, but `forward()`. The disadvantage is that you are still on `/someroute` while getting response from `/otherroute`.

Comment: exactly. that was my whole thought before ask the question. I just wondered if there was something else that could help.

Comment: I think there is no other solution, because (I believe) you can't send html and redirect reponse in one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with ZF2, but in PHP you can use

```
header('Location:www.url.com');
```

Can you try it?